# How to define a tuple of date/string in solr schema?

Tags: solr

After much searching I am not getting a lot of results. In solr schema, is it possible to define a data type that represents a pair of date/string, that is searchable?

I have documents that I would like to push to solr that looks something like this:

`{
 "itemid":"xxx",
 "valuelist":{
  {"timestamp":"2017-03-23T01:00:00.000Z","value":"firstvalue"},
  {"timestamp":"2017-03-23T02:00:00.000Z","value":"secondvalue"}
 }
}`

So how do I define the field type for members of the `valuelist` in solr schema?

It's got to be searchable on the timestamp and the value so I can't fake it by using a single string value with a custom separator. E.g. "give me all itemids between these dates", or "give me all itemids where value = secondvalue"

The only 'solution' I have been able to find is the workaround of creating multiple documents, each with the same id, and a single `timestamp` and a single `value` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do this with [nested objects](http://yonik.com/solr-nested-objects/).

One field would be the date, the other the string. One Item doc would contain a number of nested docs, and you can query them (making sure both the date and the string in the same nested object match your criteria etc)